# SWRL rules in Protege 5.1

Tags: protege, swrl

I wrote a SWRL rule in this way:

```
A(?x)->AA(?x,3)
```

I already have a class `A`, have a data property `AA`, an individual `a`.

It feels like after reasoning the data property of `a` should be `3`.

However there is no data property for `a`.

What can I do then?

Comment: Perhaps you should provide us with a little more context..

Comment: code snippet, tags highlight

Comment: **how** do you see that there is no inferred axiom `AA(a, 3)` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me with the tag.

Comment: I have checked for other questions like mine. It seems that I should enable the [b]Data Property Assertions[/b] in the Preference. Then the inferences could be seen as data property of individual.